# Browser / Server Hang while Uploading multiple files asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

There is probably an easy answer to this, but I don't know it:

The issue is that I am uploading multiple files via XMLHttpRequests, calling that from a for loop. That loops through the files that have to be uploaded (an entire folder using webkitdirectory).  That part all works if I do not have a large number of files, but I may have as many as 300 or may, probably never more than 1000.  I got the original code from a Github project here:

[UploadFolder](https://github.com/komputronika/UploadFolder), but I have edited it a little to suit my needs.  I think that the critical code is still basically the same.

After some pre-processing there is a loop that iterates through the filelist to be uploaded and calls a function to upload the files to the server:

```
for (var i = 0; i < picker.files.length; i++) {
    var file = picker.files[i];
    if (processflag[i] == false) {
        let lineitem = statusitem(file, "Skipped (.hidden file)");
        listing.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lineitem);
    }
    else {
    sendFile(file);
    }
}
```

The sendfile function is pretty long, so I've just included what are probably the key parts:

```
sendFile = function(file) {

     var timestamp  = picker.dataset.timestamp;
     var formData = new FormData();

     // Set post variables 

     requestcounter = requestcounter + 1;
     formData.set('timestamp', timestamp);
     formData.set('counter', requestcounter);
     formData.set('total', total); 
     formData.set('webkitpath', file.webkitRelativePath);
     formData.set('file', file); // One object file


     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

     request.responseType = 'json';

     // HTTP onload handler

     request.onload = function() {

         if (request.readyState === request.DONE) {

              if (request.status === 200) {

                 console.log(request.response);

                 // Does a bunch of post-processing stuff here
                 // .....
                 // .........

             }
             else {
                 // issue with request
             }
         }
     }

     // Do request
     request.open("POST", '/OrthancDev/UploadFolder');
     request.send(formData);
}
```

The HTML is not that critical.

```
<div class="picker">
    <input type="file" id="picker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple data-timestamp = "">
</div>
```

is probably the most relevant part, the timestamp get set dynamically.

On the server side there is some fairly involved processing of the POST using PHP and also execution of some install binaries like:

```
        $proc = proc_open(path_to_executable',[

        1 => ['pipe','w'],
        2 => ['pipe','w'],
        ],$pipes);
        $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        proc_close($proc);
        . . . .
```

and moving the upload to a folder on the server:

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_path);
```

The POST to the server includes:

```
-----------------------------19160542578905591423661131170
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="timestamp"
2020-05-09-15-44-36
-----------------------------19160542578905591423661131170
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="counter"
24
-----------------------------19160542578905591423661131170
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="total"
25
-----------------------------19160542578905591423661131170
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="webkitpath"
POST_T1_FS_TSE_SAG_2MM_12001/IM-0009-0025.dcm
-----------------------------19160542578905591423661131170
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="POST_T1_FS_TSE_SAG_2MM_12001/IM-0009-0025.dcm"
Content-Type: application/dicom
```

BTW, do uploaded files also go to a /tmp directory on the server ?

The issue is that with a small set of files, say like 8 or so, everything seems to work fine, but with a larger number of files (e.g. even just 25), the browser or the server "hangs".  I am running everything on a MAMP server using Apache,  and the Apache log seems fine, as does the PHP log, I am not seeing any errors there.

It does send off a number of AJAX requests in rapid succession.

I am not familiar with the "Timing tab" in the FF dev tools,but by the time the last request is made, the "Blocked" timing shows 1.38 s.  It does look like all files are getting uploaded to the server, but the browser is unresponsive thereafter for that virtual host.

I presume that it might have something to do with firing off that many asynchronous requests in succession.  I could try making those requests synchronously and see if that takes too long, or using some sort of promise, or limiting the number of active async reqeusts, but I am not sure how to do that.

I am not sure if it is a server side issue as well.  The individual files are abut 1MB, but could be larger, and the entire folder is about 256 MB, but could also be larger.

It is apparently a server side issue.  There is a process that runs an executable that seems to hang the server, and thus the browser:

```
$proc = proc_open($exec,[
    1 => ['pipe','w'],
    2 => ['pipe','w'],
],$pipes);
. . . .
```

That takes about 30 seconds to run from the command line but it does look like all files are getting sent to the server and saved, so it seems like that last process is causing the problem.

The output for that from the CLI is:

```
XMIT: .........................................................................
I: Received Store Response (Success)
I: Sending file: /Users/sscotti/Desktop/newtelerad2/dicomtemp/DEV01/2020-05-10-05-44-14/UC5457343/T1_TSE_SAGITTAL_2MM_6001/IM-0003-0021.dcm
I: Converting transfer syntax: Little Endian Explicit -> Little Endian Explicit
I: Sending Store Request (MsgID 18, MR)
```

but about 300x, 1 for each file.  Would be nice if there was a good way to parse the output from STDOUT (e.g. I, W, E)

Comment: Must be a server side issue.  If I just omit all of the server side processing and just return a status code of 200, then all of the requests are complete, all files sent, and not browser hang.